# Guzzle POST request php vs Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, guzzle

My request works fine with ajax, but fails when I tried to re-create the scenario with guzzle. I get returned with a 400 bad response. I have a feeling I maybe set something wrong in the guzzle parameters? It is my first time using this.

Ajax

```
            var usernameV5 = '108357166';
            var passwordV5 = '1234';

            var data = {
                'type':'base64', 
                'value':btoa(usernameV5 + ":" + passwordV5), 
                'namespace':'https://somelink/customers'
            };
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.ajax({
                'type':'POST',
                'headers':{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                'url':'cantshow.com',
                'data':data,
                'success':function (result) {

                },
                'error':function () {

                }
            });
```

Guzzle

```
                            $username = '108357166';
                            $password = '1234';
                            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
                            $result = $client->post('cantshow.com', [
                                'headers' => [
                                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                                ],
                                'data' => [
                                    'type' => 'base64', 
                                    'value' => base64_encode("'".$username.":".$password."'"), 
                                    'namespace' => 'https://somelink/customers'
                                ]
                            ])->getBody();
```

Comment: What version of Guzzle?

Comment: version 6.2.2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the version of guzzle being used, for 5 and 6 this should work:

```
$client->post('cantshow.com', array(
                                'headers'=>array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'),
                                'json' => array( 
                                    'type' => 'base64', 
                                    'value' => base64_encode("'".$username.":".$password."'"), 
                                    'namespace' => 'https://somelink/customers'
                                )
                            ));
```